# Kekkai Sensen ep9, meaning of "playing it backwards in double-time/fast-forward"?

Tags: kekkai-sensen

5:54 Zapp said *"What's he doin', playing it backwards in fast-forward?"* You could replace *fast-forward* with *double-time* according to another set of subtitles. He was referring to the vampire, but the vampire wasn't even doing anything. What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

The vampire they were fighting was regenerating (I guess "playing it backwards" as in "reverting to a prior, unhurt state") quickly ("in double-time").

He had previously been severely injured by crashing into the skyscraper and by Klaus's attack. Note that about 30 seconds prior (in video time, not necessarily in-show time), he looked like this:

[image: injured vampire]

I think there's a kernel of a pun in here. Zapp says 逆再生の早回しかよ *gyaku-saisei no hayamawashi ka yo*. The word 再生 *saisei* has two meanings. One, "play" as in "to play a video". Two, "regenerate" or "come back to life". The prefixal 逆 *gyaku* means "the opposite of" or "reversed". So whereas a regular creature regenerating might be "coming back to life", an eldritch undead abomination like a vampire might instead be "coming back to life backwards" - *gyaku-saisei*, which is also the word you'd use for "to play a video backwards".

I'm kind of reaching here, though; I'm not sure whether that was the intention.